# "For every variable x and y" or "For every variables x and y"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, quantifiers, software-bugs

Which one of these two sentences is grammatical?

(1) For every variable x and y, so and so...

(2) For every variables x and y, so and so...

Grammarly seems to prefer (1), but it sounds strange to my ear...

Comment: Those are not sentences.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because neither of the texts submitted to Grammarly are meaningful sequences in English. But even if they *were*, it's not our job to debug Grammarly.

Answer (score 4):

"every" is an indefinite pronoun and takes a singular noun.
e.g; Every man and woman participated in the game.
So, " for every variable "x" and "y" is the correct sentence.

Comment: Yes. Math norms use "For every variable x and y" or "For all values of x and y."

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use the plural but it uses the word 'all' instead of 'every' giving the phrase "... for all variables x and y ...".  If Grammarly genuinely suggests "... for every variables x and y ..." then it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases its useful to rewrite the sentence.

For example:

> For every variable x and y

becomes

> For every variable x and for every variable y

It is easier to notice how your second example is incorrect, since it would be rewritten as:

> For every variables x and for every variables y

Likewise,

> For all variable x and for all variable y

doesn't sound correct, but

> For all variables x and for all variables y

does.